# Android 4.x orientation with phonegap

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I've a web app with phonegap 1.3 and jquerymobile 1.0 that works well on all android version but 4.0
In fact if I change the orientation the app force close with no errors and no (as I can understand) logcat errors.
If I open my app in portrait works, If I open in landscape works but if I try to switch closes

Here's my code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.phonegap.DroidGap;
public class MYActivity extends DroidGap {
         @Override 
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    }   
}
```

of course I've

```
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" 
        android:screenOrientation="sensor"
```

in manifest !

thanks for help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding this:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
```

as your config change parameter to see if it fixes your issue.

Comment: Oh, you should always build your application with the latest SDK and let Android handle the backwards compatibility. You can specify a min sdk version that your app can run on in the manifest file. I would not go lower than 7 (Android 2.1) for this value.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same rotation problem and took the app to the latest version of the sdk 4.03, and the above mentioned configuration changes.  My manifest looks like the following:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="13" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".Ordering"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <!-- ZXing activities -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner.SCAN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.encode.EncodeActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/share_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner.ENCODE" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```