# Application crashed when orientation change

Tags: android, cordova, sencha-touch, extjs

Actually my problem is the same as the question posted in :
[the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8667489/android-4-x-orientation-with-phonegap/8724026#8724026) 
But there is no answer yet..

**Here is the problem I got :** 
I've just built an application using sencha touch & phone gap. It runs well on my galaxy tab but when I rotate it to portrait or landscape, it is going crash. 
I have added :

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```

on my manifest file but it is still going crash when I rotate it.
I don't know how could this happen. 
Could someone help me?

Note : 
I'm using 
- Galaxy tab 
- Sencha-touch 1.1 
- Phone gap 1.2

Comment: Please post the Logcat messages.

Comment: Thanks Karthik for your reply :), but there are no any errors in the Logcat. It's suddenly closed without any errors or notifications. Any solutions for this?

Comment: oh, so by crash you mean the app restarts? because if it crashes, there should be some exception. See if you get any warning or info logs.

Comment: Hi Karthik, I tried to recompile my application on different version of eclipse & upgrade my phonegap too 1.3, it works now.. But I don't know exactly what the problem is.., because when I tried to use phonegap 1.2 again, it works. Hmmm.., i don't know if it is about eclipse version. Thanks for your support Karthik :)

Comment: Do you have different resources for landscape and portrait? it maybe because of some problem in compilation, the resources may not have been placed into the APK properly. I also have faced this issue. A clean build solves it. Anyway, welcome :)

Comment: No, I don't have any different resources. I just follow the basic configuration from phonegap site and test it on my device :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should have

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout"
```

instead of

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```

to your activity in the manifest

Comment: android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout"
It worked for me.. thank you.

Comment: @Yagi: please mark it right if it is working for you it is working for me.So users find it is useful. Thanks

Comment: I'm sory, for being late to confirm this question. @mauriziopz: Thanks, it works for me :).

Answer (score 8):

Might be a bit late... but since I've recently been trying this, I found that specifying

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
```

works where as

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout"
```

does NOT.

I'm using cordova 2.0.0.