# Application closes when device is rotated

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm testing via USB debugging on my Galaxy Tab 8.9 and whenver I rotate the device the application closes itself.

How can i fix this?

Comment: What application? Code? Something? You're not new here. -1.

Comment: Don't rotate the device! Sorry someone had to say it... jking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having the same problem but Yaron Uliel's comment helped me out.

Just make sure that on yout "AndroidManifest.xml", the 'activity' node has the attribute:
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"

Like this:

```
<activity
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" 
    android:name=".FirstAppActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
```

In my particlar case, I was missing "**android:**" part before "configChanges=" (it's an error on Adobe's tutorial I believe)

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

[Android 4.x orientation with phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8667489/android-4-x-orientation-with-phonegap)

add this line your activity in the manifest

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
```

Answer (score 1):

For me I found out, that the android:configChanges-Entry must be the first in the list. I had it in the third after "name" and "label" and it didn't work.